# Calculate GPS position every second in the background?[Xamarin Android]

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

Started programming in Android and i seem to have problems with having something running continuously in the background.
This is the code that i have in MainActivity

```
async Task task()
{
var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;
var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMilliseconds: 10000);
var speed = position.Speed * 3.6;
speedKmh = speed.ToString() + "km/h";
}
```

i want it to start at the beginning of the application and basically run it every 1 second so i can display the device's speed using GPS.It must be really simple but i just don't know how.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That task will run once, get the position and finish. Unless you launch it externally each second, you need to create a loop and add a delay:

```
//Defined somewhere else
bool runGPS = false;
Task currentGPS = null;

async Task task()
{
    while(runGPS)
    {
        var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
        locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;
        var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMilliseconds: 10000);
        var speed = position.Speed * 3.6;
        speedKmh = speed.ToString() + "km/h";
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }

    currentGPS = null;
}
```

Also I would recommend to create two methods to start/stop the task:

```
bool StartGPS()
{
    if(currentGPS != null)
        return false;

    runGPS = true;
    currentGPS = task();

    return true;
}

bool StopGPS()
{
    if(currentGPS == null)
        return false;

    runGPS = false;

    return true;
}
```

Finally, if you need to update exactly each second then instead of waiting for a fixed delay you must create a Stopwatch, measure the time it has taken to read the GPS data and delay `1000 - stopWatch.EllapsedMilliseconds`.